Identity: Symmetric Polynomials in Roots of Unity
Good people! Once more, I appeal to you for help!
In Lamé's (failed) proof of Fermat's Last Theorem, he makes use of the fact that if $n$ is a prime number, $r$ is a primitive $n^{\text{th}}$ root of unity, and $s_k(x_0,x_1,\dots,x_{n-1})$ is the $k^{\text{th}}$ symmetric polynomial in $n$ variables, then $s_k(1,r,r^2,\dots,r^{n-1})=0$ for $0<k\leq n$ and $s_k(1,r,r^2,\dots,r^{n-1})=1$. I have seen this stated as an identity elsewhere, although sadly without proof.
At first glance, this seems to be one of those identities that should be easy to prove by just being clever, but alas, I have now spent my entire Saturday afternoon going at it, and I either find myself going in circles, or I find myself lost in the nitty gritty of keeping track of far too many things when I try making use of the multinomial theorem. I feel like the real proof in all likelihood is much simpler than that.
All I am certain of is that the proof has to reply on some clever way of making use of the identity $1+r+r^2+\dots+r^{n-1}=0$.
Any takers?

Maybe start from $$ x^n-1=\prod_{i=0}^{n-1} (x-r^i)$$ and use Vieta's formula? Or I misunderstand your problem?

JESUS FUCKING CHRIST, YOU'RE A GENIUS, SIR/MA'AM! And what makes this even more embarrassing is that I have seen a similar use of Vieta's formulas in the past when dealing with symmetric polynomials! THANK YOU! YOU SOLVED IT! :D

Zoudelong was able to solve the problem immediately, and to make matters more embarrassing, when I was reading Hensel's Theory of Algebraic Numbers three years ago, I actually now remember seeing something that looked very similar. Anyway, to give you the solution, following Zoudelong's hint!
It follows from definition of a primitive root of unity that
$$x^n - 1 = \prod_{i=0}^{n-1} (x-r^{i}).$$
Simply writing the right-hand-side out, we have
$$x^n - 1 = x^n - s_1 (1,r,r^2,\dots,r^{n-1}) x^{n-1} + s_2 (1,r,r^2,\dots,r^{n-1}) x^{n-2} + \dots - s_n (1,r,r^2,\dots,r^{n-1}),$$
from whence we easily read off the desired information that $s_k (1,r,r^2,\dots,r^{n-1}) = 0$ for $0<k<n$ and $s_n (1,r,r^2,\dots,r^{n-1}) = 1$.
All very neat and clever!
